# How to make the PUT method work? I want to update my data in Table

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, put

This is my POST method and it is successful and run well. My question is how to do the PUT request method so that it can update the data well?

### Post method

```
public void addRecipe(RecipeDTO recipedto)
{
    Category categoryTitle = categoryRepository.findByCategoryTitle(recipedto.getCategoryTitle());
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe();

   /*I map my dto data original model*/

    recipe.setRID(recipedto.getrID());
    recipe.setRecipeTitle(recipedto.getRecipeTitle());
    recipe.setDescription(recipedto.getDescription());
    recipe.setCookTime(recipedto.getCookTime());

    List categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    categoryList.add(categoryTitle);

    recipe.setCategories(categoryList);

    Recipe savedRecipe = recipeRepository.save(recipe);


    /*I map the data in ingredientDTO and setpDTO to actual model */

    List ingredientList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(IngredientDTO ingredientdto : recipedto.getIngredients())
    {   
        Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();

        ingredient.setIID(ingredientdto.getiID());
        ingredient.setIngredientName(ingredientdto.getIngredientName());
        ingredient.setRecipe(savedRecipe);

        ingredientList.add(ingredient);

    }

    List stepList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(StepDTO stepdto : recipedto.getSteps())
    {   
        Step step = new Step();

        step.setSID(stepdto.getsID());
        step.setStepDescription(stepdto.getStepDescription());
        step.setStepNumber(stepdto.getStepNumber());
        step.setRecipe(savedRecipe);


        stepList.add(step);

    }

    ingredientRepository.save(ingredientList);
    stepRepository.save(stepList);


}
```

This is my put method and it wont work, how should I do it, because I have no idea. Please teach me to do this method, if it is better.

```
public void updateRecipe(RecipeDTO recipedto, String id)
{
    Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findByrID(recipedto.getrID());
    if(id==recipedto.getrID().toString())
    {
        recipeRepository.save(recipe);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When building REST services in Java you usually use an Framework to help you with this.

Like "jax-rs": https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0
If using jax-rs then you mark your method as an Http PUT method with the annotation @PUT, ex:

```
@PUT
@Path("ex/foo")
public Response somePutMethod() {
  return Response.ok().entity("Put some Foos!").build();
}
```

If using Spring as an Framework you mark your PUT method with the @RequestMapping annotation, ex:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ex/foo", method = PUT)
public String putFoos() {
    return "Put some Foos";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly and very importantly, you **DO NOT** use String == String for checking equality. Your code:

```
public void updateRecipe(RecipeDTO recipedto, String id)
{
    Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findByrID(recipedto.getrID());
    if(id==recipedto.getrID().toString())
    {
        recipeRepository.save(recipe);
    }
}
```

It should be:

```
public void updateRecipe(RecipeDTO recipedto, String id)
    {
        Recipe recipe = recipeRepository.findByrID(recipedto.getrID());
        if(recipedto.getrID().toString().equals(id))
        {
            recipeRepository.save(recipe);
        }
    }
```

Why?
Because equality with == checks if objects have the same memory address. In other words:

```
new Integer(1) == new Integer(1) //false
1 == 1 //true
new String("hello") == new String("hello") //false
"hello" == "hello" //true because literal strings are stored in a String pool
new String("hello") == "hello" //false
```

Secondly, you **SHOULD ALWAYS** use generics with Collection APIs.
Your code:

```
List categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Should be:

```
List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And lastly, like askepan said, you have not defined what framework you are using. In case of Jersey (JAX-RS implementation) you have HTTP Request Methods:
@GET, @POST, @PUT, @DELETE, @HEAD, @OPTIONS.

```
@PUT
@Produces("text/plain")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public Response putContainer() {
    System.out.println("PUT CONTAINER " + container);

    URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath();
    Container c = new Container(container, uri.toString());

    Response r;
    if (!MemoryStore.MS.hasContainer(c)) {
        r = Response.created(uri).build();
    } else {
        r = Response.noContent().build();
    }
    MemoryStore.MS.createContainer(c);
    return r;
}
```

If you use Spring, there are @RequestMapping(method = ), or short versions:
@GetMapping, @PutMapping, @PostMapping, @DeleteMapping.

```
   @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Person getPerson(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void add(@RequestBody Person person) {
        // ...
    }
```

According to the annotation, the method will be called accordingly.

More information in: 
[Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping),[JAX-RS](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2040)